# How can move event be banned in UITableView during the previous move event datasource operation is in progress?

Tags: ios, uitableview

Each time when user moves a row in tableView it triggers a database operation. Until operation completes, user should be not allowed to initiate a new move event. Any idea how to ban it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need `self.tableView.setEditing(false, animated: true)` at beginning of `moveRowAtIndexPath` and `self.tableView.setEditing(true, animated: true)` end of the dataSource delegate method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Following Delegate Method.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndReorderingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add [MBProgressHUD](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/mbprogresshud) until operation completes.